# Are there any options for high speed file sharing in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have two VMs using the same vnet and I would like to be able to copy a directory that has thousands of files and is about 400mb.

I can use a UNC path to copy the files, but that takes 2 minutes.  I’ve also tried using a storage account and created a file share, but that is also slow.

Are there any other Azure resources that might make getting files from one VM to another faster?

Comment: Are the VM's and VNET in the same region? Are you using VNET (private) adresses? or internet addresses for the UNC?

Comment: Yes, same region and I'm using private addresss

Answer (score 0):

As the comment point it out, if you have two VMs in the same VNet, you should use its private address. Traffic between the two VMs is kept on the Azure backbone network. You could directly copy/paste the files from one VM to another VM when you RDP to that VM.

Also, different VM size has different performance. For the best performance, It's recommended that you migrate any VM disk that requires high IOPS to Premium Storage. VM disks that use Premium Storage store data on solid-state drives (SSDs).

[High-performance Premium Storage and managed disks for VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/premium-storage)